# Is there a way to easly bind a grid to a table in Xamarin, like in my WinForms code?

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am new to xamarin, i need to easily link a grid (or something similar) to my MySql database table.
In WinForms I had done it by putting a grid with the designer and with a few lines of code, but instead with Xamarin I can't do anything ...
My current project is a XamarinForm with the default "tab" preset.

Here is the WinForm code:

```
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection cnn;
            string connetionString = "server=sql7.freesqldatabase.com;database=------;port=----;uid=-------;pwd=------;";
            cnn = new MySqlConnection(connetionString);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            MySqlCommand cmd;
            cnn.Open();

            cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from Products";
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; //dataGridView WinFrom component

            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Is there a way to do this in Xamarin?
(my goal is to display all the db table in one page)

Comment: you need a DataGrid control.  XF does not have one built-in, but there are several commercial and open source alternatives available

Comment: you can try a collectionview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/

Comment: ok i have added a grid (Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid), but how to bind it with my code up here?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Although there is not the same way that **Xamarin** can use `DataTable` as Source directly, but there is an another way to convert Table Date and make it used for Control(Such as `CollectionView`, `DataGrid`, etc).

For example, ItemSource can be set as follows:

```
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = await TodoItemDatabase.Database.Table<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();
```

Here the `TodoItem` is the Model of table data, you need to create it in Xamarin Forms manually. Then the app will convert the table data to list data according to the model style.

```
using SQLite;
public class TodoItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
}
```

About using **Databases** in Xamarin, you can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases).And there is [a sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/todo) for reference. Above code **TodoItemDatabase** class also based on this sample.

Here is the **TodoItemDatabase** class:

```
public class TodoItemDatabase
{
    static readonly Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection> lazyInitializer = new Lazy<SQLiteAsyncConnection>(() =>
    {
        return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
    });

    public static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database => lazyInitializer.Value;
    static bool initialized = false;

    public TodoItemDatabase()
    {
        InitializeAsync().SafeFireAndForget(false);
    }

    async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        if (!initialized)
        {
            if (!Database.TableMappings.Any(m => m.MappedType.Name == typeof(TodoItem).Name))
            {
                await Database.CreateTablesAsync(CreateFlags.None, typeof(TodoItem)).ConfigureAwait(false);                    
            }
            initialized = true;
        }
    }

    public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        return Database.Table<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsNotDoneAsync()
    {
        return Database.QueryAsync<TodoItem>("SELECT * FROM [TodoItem] WHERE [Done] = 0");
    }

    public Task<TodoItem> GetItemAsync(int id)
    {
        return Database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        if (item.ID != 0)
        {
            return Database.UpdateAsync(item);
        }
        else
        {
            return Database.InsertAsync(item);
        }
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteItemAsync(TodoItem item)
    {
        return Database.DeleteAsync(item);
    }
}
```

And **Constants** class which contains database name and other things.

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string DatabaseFilename = "TodoSQLite.db3";

    public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
        // open the database in read/write mode
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
        // create the database if it doesn't exist
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
        // enable multi-threaded database access
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

    public static string DatabasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            return Path.Combine(basePath, DatabaseFilename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i have made a class with all the the variables (like Id, name, ...), but what's next?

Comment: @Jolink Next you need to generate a database instance, then can get the table data as above code: `TodoItemDatabase.Database.Table<TodoItem>().ToListAsync()`. Have a look at the shared sample project. And I also have updated it in my answer now.